# OS X Lion Connection to Business network?

Tags: macos, network, vpn, remote-control

I have a client that wants to connect an OS X Lion macbook air to his business network remotely, and I was just wondering if anyone knows of a way to do this easily. Normally, I would set up a VPN server and allow for a connection in this way, but that is not a process I can recommend to "less techy" people. Is there an easier (while still secure) way to set up a business network connection remotely? Thanks beforehand.

Answer (score 3):

I don't see a reason not to set up a VPN. You can add the VPN menu to the status bar and your client can simply select their VPN and enter a password when prompted. It's no more difficult than say, a TeamViewer connection setup. (In fact, VPN is arguably easier, since the system stores your username and merely prompts for a password. TeamVewer requires an ID and a password.)

I *just* began using VPN this week, and it's super easy. Really. To add VPN to the status bar:

[image: Add VPN to Status Bar]

Then, your client can simply click to connect, like so:

[image: Click to connect to VPN]

<sup>(VPN info blurred for security reasons.)</sup>

Comment: I fully agree with you. The VPN setup in Lion is quite easy.

Answer (score 0):

You could try programs like [Hamachi](https://secure.logmein.com/products/hamachi/default.aspx) or even [Teamviewer](http://www.teamviewer.com/) which now supports VPN. They both have easy to use installers for the less tech-savvy.

Otherwise if you have access to a Mac computer, you can [create(export) a network preference file](http://docs.info.apple.com/article.html?path=Mac/10.6/en/8722.html) which can be double-clicked to automatically load the VPN settings.